# OS X Mountain Lion shortcut menu

Tags: macos, dock, menu-bar

I just switched from a PC (Ubuntu 12.10) to a Macbook Pro (Mountain Lion). I'd like to know if there's a way to have a similar shortcut menu on the dock as I had on Ubuntu's sidebar? Basically I made a clickable menu to run a bunch of expect scripts so I wouldn't have to do it through the terminal.
Here's how it looks in ubuntu:

[image: ubuntu desktop script]

I used a .desktop config file to add each menu item and then dragged it onto the sidebar. So my question is - what are the ways to have something like this in OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) is a menu bar application for running scripts:

[image]

Automator services aren't really usable in 10.8 or 10.7, but see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) for other ways to assign shortcuts to scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at one of

- [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/)

  > Alfred saves you time when you search for files online or on your Mac. Be more productive with hotkeys, keywords and file actions at your fingertips.
- [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)

  > Keyboard Maestro 5 is now available with control flow, variables, calculations, file actions, image manipulation, macro library and more.
  >
  > Keyboard Maestro is a powerful macro program for Mac OS X Mountain Lion, Lion and Snow Leopard which has received glowing reviews.

Especially Alfred works like a command line for O X and gives you the option to control most of your system interaction with simple text commands. If you prefer menus and mouse clicks, Keyboard Maestro might be the better choice.